# Xamarin Media Plugin on UWP for using Camera

Tags: uwp, xamarin.forms, media

I am getting below error while using [Media Plugin] (https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin) in Xamarin Forms PCL

Value does not fall within the expected range. (List dictionary internal)

This plugin works well with Android & iOS. For UWP it works well with picking photo from gallery but for camera it is throwing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making mistake of giving special char (?) in directory to save photos however same works for android & iOS

Incorrect ----

```
  MediaFile mediaFile = await iMedia.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                            {
                                SaveToAlbum = true,
                                CompressionQuality = 50,
                                PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                                **Directory = "XYZ? ",**                           
                            });
```

Correct ---

```
  MediaFile mediaFile = await iMedia.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions
                        {
                            SaveToAlbum = true,
                            CompressionQuality = 50,
                            PhotoSize = PhotoSize.Medium,
                            **Directory = "XYZ",**
                            Name = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".png"
                        });
```